# decremental div width for sub-navigation points

Tags: html, css

I am building a navigation in angular which loads subpoints that are indented (I hope it's the right word).
So main nav-points will be on the very left of the navigation bar, sub nav-points will have a margin-left to have them indented a little bit. Futhermore, sub-sub nav-points will have a higher margin to have them indented further.

Now on it's own, this works just fine.

My issue is that I also need to display buttons on the very right side of the navigation bar that are not indented.

Since the navigation is loaded recursively and the buttons are for the individual navigation points, I can not place them in the parent.

Currently, html/css wise, this looks somewhat like this:

Parent - html

```
<div class="nav">
  <items [items]="items" [subNavToggle]="false"></items>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <content></content>
</div>
```

Parent - css

```
.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 245px;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
```

item/navpoint - hmtl

```
<div class="item" [class.subnav]="subNavToggle">
  <div class="link"><a [routerLink]="[item.path]">{{ item.label }}</a></div>
  <div class="edit-button"><img [src]="icon" /></div>
<div class="children indented">
  <items [items]="items.children" [subNavToggle]="true"><items>
</div>
```

item/navpoint css

```
.item.subnav {
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.indented{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 105%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 231px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0dede;
}

.link {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
}

.edit-button {
  float: right;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 12px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

Now due to the div around the recursive call inside the items having the indented class, the further down the sub-navigation I go, the further indented it gets.
The issue are the buttons, with further indention(?) they are pushed further off to the right. I'd want them to be the same distance from the right border of the navigation-box.

The html structure aspect of the buttons being inside the items can sadly not be changed.

My goal now is the decrease the width of the sub-items with each further recursive step to somehow align the buttons properly. sadly toying with the width property has not given me the results I hoped for.

As with the code above, the whole thing looks like this: [image]

now, how can I get all the buttons properly aligned?

Comment: Probably off topic, but what's with the bracketed attributes? I mean, `<img [src]="icon" />`?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with only css and html, so we can test it easily ? you can just copy/paste your html generated in your browser.

Comment: @MrLister that's basicly me loading an image I have saved in the project folders, shortened the whole thing a little

Comment: @Pierre Granger does that just work that easily without the logic or navpoints behind it? Well, does not matter too much, the answer posted below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding position relative on .item class.

```
.item {
    position:relative;
}
```

Then use absolute to align the icon.

```
.edit-button {
    position:absolute;
    right:0; or right:10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: was not aware there was an attribute like "right" but it works like a charm, thank you.